# PhD after marriage

Tags: international-students, age

I am 28 year old international student (Male, if it matters for the question ahead) and am about to graduate with a Masters degree in a foreign country. I want to pursue a PhD and have a few offers. But I don't think I am in the right frame of mind to do so immediately. Financially, I want to pay off my debts and also have a sufficient balance in my bank account. Personally, I feel insecure that I have never been in a relationship before and would like to settle down with someone. Also, I Everywhere I see, people are in relationships I think that I need a source of support while doing my PhD. I wanted to know everyone's thoughts about this from the people in academia. Is it a good idea to do a PhD after marriage? So far, I've heard only negative things about it but I don't think I am ready yet. Are there people who have been in happy marriages while doing a PhD? Why is it hard to do a PhD and be married? And lastly, is me letting go of my opportunity in hand, while being unmarried a bad idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get how that even is of concern.

Comment: You are good to go. A good percentage of PhD scholars are married before starting their research or in the middle of their research. Some keep committed relationship in their lives during PhD. But you have to have a good understanding with your partner (or whatever you call it), then it is alright. I am married before my PhD and and soon will submit my thesis with 3-4 research publications in hand. So it depends on you how you manage everything.

Comment: While it is true that this depends on individual factors, I think it is a common enough concern in academia that it is worth keeping open and I've so voted.

Comment: "Financially, I want to pay off my debts and also have a sufficient balance in my bank account."
A PhD is not for you.

Comment: @Buffy: Well, if you want this to be answered in general, you can arguably write a book about it – i.e., the question you think deserves an answer too broad. This is demonstrated by the existing answers, which either focus on particular aspects or state that they can only scratch the surface. While there are certainly good questions to be asked about PhDs and marriage, these need to be more specific. This does not necessarily be about one individual’s experience but can focus on a particular possible problem, e.g. financial aspects, time devotion, etc.

Comment: Moreover, this question (and the existing answers) likely come with some inherent cultural assumptions about marriage. While there is nothing wrong with such assumptions per se, they need to be spelt out – otherwise everybody will talk about different things and the answers advice will not be helpful to the asker (and others) since it clashes with their assumptions on marriage.

Comment: Is it possible in your place to just start dating and look where it goes? Some sentances in the question look slighly odd to me - maybe it is just good to try, date and see how you like it?

Comment: I started my PhD 2 months after got married. In a year for 1st kid. Everything is fine. Now, after 8 years, I am a PhD in Astrophysics with 2 kids, working as ML engineer in big tech company.

Comment: @circassia_ai - Which country are you in? I think a PhD in EU is much more structured than in the US, in terms of work life balance

Answer (score 6):

People enter graduate school unmarried and leave unmarried. They enter married and leave married. They enter single and leave married. And many also enter married and leave divorced. Graduate school is not some monastery, but just another type of job training, and like every type of training, it has its quirks.

Being married while in grad school has some benefits. To some people, it gives some structure, for example, you know you have to leave the lab/library/classroom by certain time to be home with your partner. It also brings a lot of complications. Lots of grad student partners complain that the grad student has a nice life, surrounded by interesting people, traveling to conferences, doing research that matters, while they (the partners) go to work every day and live so-so lives.

If you marry another graduate student, you might find yourself with a [two-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_(career)) when looking for jobs.

There are other issues which are particular to graduate school and how they affect grad students' relationships (or lack of thereof), but in general, it's just the same shit as everywhere else.

Comment: Let me add that all of those things also might apply if you are "just" in a relationship, not married.

Answer (score 1):

If one is married **and has young kids**, that can put a lot of pressure on one’s spouse since a PhD program can take over one’s attention, even when one is “with” the family. Both the spouse and the kids can become resentful.

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to the fact that I have to take care of the baby round the clock? In that case, I found that universities offer childcare facilities like https://hokiewellness.vt.edu/Employees/work-life/Child_Care.html. Would that take some weight off my shoulder or are you saying that it's going to be hard even with this arrangement?

Comment: My point was about the burden on one’s spouse. Whatever childcare you can arrange, a great deal still falls to the parents. So the less available **you** are—and grad students can be pretty unavailable for anything besides their studies—the more ends up in your spouse’s lap.

Comment: Let me add that there are a lot of phd students who take care of their kids (and work less), just as in any other job.